# SwiftUI Sheet background flickering when mapping around

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using the new .presentationBackground view modifier to make the background of the sheet a translucent material. From this sheet, I have two nested sheets. In the background of the sheet, I have a pannable map and have also enabled .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled) for the sheet's content. Here's whats happening, whenever I pan around the map or a published property in my view model updates due to a ping to my backend, the sheet's background flickers from the default value. I'm not able to attach videos, but here's a screenshot of the sheet background in a state where it's not showing the translucent background at all.

[image: Demo]

Here is the following code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var showSheet1 = false
   @State var showSheet2 = false

   var body: some View {
      UserLocationMap(locManager: locManager).ignoresSafeArea()
         .sheet(isPresented: $showingMainActivity) {
           // ActivitySheet(isLoadingForFirstTime: $isLoadingForFirstTime, addFriends: $addFriends)
            Text("Hello")
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.4), .fraction(0.95)])
                .presentationBackground(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
                .sheetThatFitsContentInside(isPresented: $editProfile, sheetHeight: $editProfileSheetHeight) {
                    Text("World")
                        .padding(100)
                        .padding(.vertical, 100)
                }
        }
   }
}

struct UserLocationMap: View {
    @ObservedObject var locManager: LocationManager
        
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $locManager.region,
            interactionModes: .all,
            showsUserLocation: true)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func sheetThatFitsContentInside<Content>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
                                             sheetHeight: Binding<CGFloat>,
                                             expandable: Bool = false,
                                             content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View where Content : View {
        self.sheet(isPresented: isPresented) {
            content()
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear.preference(key: InnerHeightPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
                    }
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(InnerHeightPreferenceKey.self) { newHeight in
                    sheetHeight.wrappedValue = newHeight
                }
                .presentationDetents([.height(sheetHeight.wrappedValue)])
        }
    }
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @Published var userLoc: CLLocation?
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locations.last.map { loc in
            userLoc = loc
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc.coordinate.latitude, longitude: loc.coordinate.longitude),
                                        latitudinalMeters: 1000,
                                        longitudinalMeters: 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! The flickering is very prominent, and often times, the sheet won't even have a translucent background until after some interactions have happened. I've already tried creating custom views to constrain changing published values, but what happens is that it works for a bit and then returns to it's normal behavior. Not sure if this is a bug with the modifier or if I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: Have found an answer/solution? I'm facing exactly the same issue, also with the translucent sheet above the map...

Comment: Have you messed with background opacity at all?

Comment: If you ask me - I didn't.

Comment: I think that because of Published property from ur view model. Try to avoid it or refactor somehow, I can't provide you more info, because from your example I can't understand what property are triggered and how you init your view model. I'm faced similar issue once, and I refactor some code to listen to State property neither Published

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found the cause of the problem for my case (not necessarily the exact issue that triggers the problem for the topic starter though).

First, I created a MRE: simple app with just a map, sheet over it and a `TabView` inside (because in my case, the resetting of the background happened when I swiped the tabs in the nested `TabView`). It worked flawlessly! I.e. in the sample code, where I wanted to pin down the issue, there was no issue!

Therefore, I started removing things one by one in my actual app trying to spot when it will start working properly again, because now I knew that there must be some problem in my actual code.

And guess what? I had a `.fullScreenCover` where I presented the `SFSafariViewController` (in order to open a URL inside the app). As soon as I removed it, the bug disappeared. I don't really know why `SFSafariViewController` messes up the background, but I didn't have time to investigate it further, so I just removed it and started opening links outside of my app in a default browser.

Not sure if this exact suggestion will help anyone else, but at least you can try the same debugging strategy: start removing things one by one from your app and, at some point, you will notice that the bug doesn't get reproduced anymore, which would mean that you've found the problematic component. Then, you can either try to fix it, or just work it around somehow.